# Customizing Comments

Tags: customization, comments

Hi I want to customize the text with the arrows pointed at at the image I have uploaded. I have managed to customize some but I cannot find the file to customize the rest.[image]

Many thanks

its on local host, and it is a custom theme.

Comment: Please **edit your question** to include your current code, and what you've tried regarding modifying the indicated text strings.

Comment: You will need to check comments.php and the style in style.css that modifies that.

Comment: Cheers guys all done now

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Presumably you've used [`wp_list_comments`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_list_comments) to display the comments. That being the case, what you need to do is create a callback function to format your comments and pass that callback into `wp_list_comments` like so:

```
wp_list_comments(array('callback'=>'mytheme_comment'));
```

You can use the [`comment` method](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-includes/comment-template.php#L1692) in the `Walker_Comment` class as a starting point. That method provides the default output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm wondering what is the signature of the callback. On the link you provided it is

```
function comment( $comment, $depth, $args )
```

But for example in twentyten it's different:

```
twentyten_comment( $comment, $args, $depth )
```

Source: [TwentyTen SVN trac](http://core.trac.wordpress.org/browser/trunk/src/wp-content/themes/twentyten/functions.php#L364)